# Connect MS Access Database (.mdb) using ip address with VB.NET Application

Tags: vb.net

I am connecting my VB.NET windows application to server. I am using this code:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\162.222.225.78\httpdocs\CM.mdb;"
con.Open()

MsgBox("Database is now open")

con.Close()

MsgBox("Database is now Closed")
```

But I am getting error:

> '\162.222.225.78\httpdocs\version.txt' is not a valid path. Make sure
>   that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to
>   the server on which the file resides.

Please help.

Comment: you cant directly connect with database if you use ip ! oki :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the issue for mdw file  which is your OLEDB is not finding.

search the .mdw file and copy it in that folder where your mdb file is present.

if it not works do the below..

add  Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = "password" to your connection string

like this..

"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=162.222.225.78/CRM.mdb;User=corpopef;Password=******;Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = "password(try the admin password here)""

if it also not works

write the connection string as "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=162.222.225.78/CRM.mdb;persist security info=false"

have you tried to find connection from the container's(from tool box) properties on page??

Answer (score -1):

Please do two things..

1- take a container control(like datagrid) on your page choose datasource from gridview task,

it will connect to your database where ever it is then copy that connection string from there.

definitly it will work.

2-if it does'nt work plz restart your system as the MS access databse shows this type of problems.

Comment: i changed the cooection string to "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=162.222.225.78/CRM.mdb;User=corpopef;Password=******;" i am getting an error saying Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user. plz help.. plz